# Can't compile C++ code in vscode MacOS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write c++ using vscode on Mac, but I kept receiving this error when trying to run any code.

The code I want to run:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

The error I got:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/joanne/Desktop/C++/" && g++ Hello.cpp -o Hello && "/Users/joanne/Desktop/C++/"Hello
In file included from /Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/cwchar:44:0,
                 from /Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from Hello.cpp:1:
/Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/wchar.h:29:24: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next "wchar.h"
                        ^
compilation terminated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.096 seconds
```

Some information:

macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Xcode 10.4.1

```
$ clang --version
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/joanne/anaconda3/bin
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
$ which gcc
/Users/joanne/anaconda3/bin/gcc
```

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I have also installed `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin` with homebrew.

My includepath setting:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/include/",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++",
                "/Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/include/c++/9.3.0/x86_64-apple-darwin19",
                "/Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/include/c++/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/Library/Apple/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried `open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`
But it doesn’t work cause there’s no file named `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` in macOS Catalina anymore I guess?

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/*` and `/Users/joanne/anaconda3/gcc/*` are doing here: Xcode already provides a compiler and all the necessary headers and libraries. Why is `gcc` in `/Users/joanne/anaconda3/bin/gcc`? You seem to have like 3 toolchains installed.

Comment: I have Anaconda installed a while ago (still actively using for python projects). For some reasons, vscode kept using the gcc from my anaconda directory. I tried to change to /usr/bin/gcc  but it didn’t work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.